# How to align ASCII graphic characters on a webpage?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to draw a text-based GUI in HTML (just for fun) which looks like an old terminal app and I have ran into a problem:

When I have two lines (divs) and I put graphic characters in them like these:

```
░░░
░░░
```

I can't align the lines properly (vertically). If I just put terminal characters in my divs like this:

```
<div class="line">&blk14;&block;&boxV;&lhblk;&uhblk;</div>
<div class="line">&blk14;&block;&boxV;&lhblk;&uhblk;</div>
```

there is a little spacing between them. (probably height/line-height issue).

If I style them like this:

```
.line {
    height: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

they overlap. I tried to fine-tune the values by hand but it seems that `height` and `line-height` does not work together well for example with `font-size: 40px` and `line-height: 40px` I have to use a height value of `45.5px`. What is the problem with my approach? Is there a simple way to align my lines without fine-tuning?

**Note that** I zeroed all spacings/margins/paddings and I also checked the calculated css in developer tools so it is not an issue with either of these.

My base css is this:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a funny project :) Line height should accomplish most of it but, of course, whatever font your browser is using may have glyphs of any actual size.

Comment: Seems like that `fontSize * 1.1375` works like a charm but I don't know why. I derived the formula from my example but there must be some hidden rule behind the scenes.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/VilleKoo/6vw7w2a8/ you want it like this? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: The code you linked does not work. The lines overlap.

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the height and line-height and just use a font-size (say ... of 5em) in your line style?

Answer (score 0):

I'd add `font-family: monospace` at least, see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sha589wq/).

But to be honest I'd go with a `pre` tag and if neccesary `spans` - and not do line by line div.

Comment: Oh, _vertically_ - missed that part

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this on the edge browser. I don't know what will happen on other browsers.
Bare in mind that for smaller font sizes (under .5em), some glyphs may become obscured based on monitor resolution, browser, and size.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>page title</title>
    <style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body {
        font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
    }
    .line {
        /* height: 1em; */
        /* line-height: 1em; */
        font-size: 5em;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="line">&blk14;&block;&boxV;&lhblk;&uhblk;</div>
    <div class="line">&blk14;&block;&boxV;&lhblk;&uhblk;</div>
</body>
</html>
```